# is it possible it use IAsyncCollector without taking a dependency on azure webjobs?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

I am writing a library of various business logic, and would like this to be able to interface with azure functions. I would like to receive a message sink for notifications my code wishes to produce, and IAsyncCollector seems like a reasonable interface (which has a close to trivial 2 function call interface definition), which can also be trivially provided to me within azure function app calls.

Is it possible for the library that i'm writing to accept an IASyncColector without having to add all of azure webjobs as a dependency for my library for just this one interface?

Alternatively, should the the inner code could just generate the messages, and return them to the host for adding to the collector, even though that is messy code requiring wraping each function call in a 'foreach'?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/IAsyncCollector.cs

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to get a message collector if there are multiple messages. However I don't know why you want to use `IAsyncCollector` cause the description about this type is write-only collection, you could check the doc:[Writing multiple output values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#writing-multiple-output-values).

And if you don't want to use webjob sdk, that means you could not use the storage binding, and you still want to do actions to multiple messages:

Receive messages, use [GetMessages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.getmessages?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) method, it will return an enumerable collection of messages.

Send messages, just use the List then loop it and do the add action, or just bind the `CloudQueue` type and use the `AddMessage` method.

```
            CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            CloudQueue queue1 = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");
            CloudQueue queue2 = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queue1");
            IEnumerable<CloudQueueMessage> messages= queue1.GetMessages(10);
            List<CloudQueueMessage> messages1=new List<CloudQueueMessage>();
            foreach (var message in messages) {
                Console.WriteLine(message.AsString);
                messages1.Add(message);
            }
            foreach (var message in messages1) {
                queue2.AddMessage(message);
            }
```

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem about you have to use `IAsyncCollector` please let me know.

Comment: yes, i do want the write only collection, so that my library can produce some output, and the user of the library can choose where the output goes. At the moment my library can be used in several non-azure related places, so i'd prefer to not add the azure dependency for just the 1 interface.

Comment: Suppose for now no method directly send messages, you have to wrapper a class to implement it. If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.